# Нужна помощ с git

Tags: django

есть djngo проект на компьютере, его же я выложил на git hub. как сделать так чтобы после внесения изменений на компьютере, эти изменения можно было отразить на сервере с моим проектом (сервер linode).

Comment: отправить изменения на github (push), на Вашем сервере получить с github (pull)

Comment: спасибо за ответ. а нужно на сервере с помощью команды git init создавать пустой реп? или нужно копировать репозиторий? если копировать то откуда с github или локального компьютера?

Comment: копировать с github.  при необходимости на сервере выполняете pull запрос и получаете все изменения с github